# how to dict to dict[itr]

Tags: python, dictionary

what is the appropriate way of copying a dict to a dict with array of dict and avoid overwriting of the values.

trying to copy a dict to an dict with array of dict overwrites the value.

```
import copy


l_mapFrameInfo = dict()
l_frame = dict()


itr =0

for Frames in FramesList:

l_frameInfo['name'] = Frames.get('name')    
l_frameInfo['number'] = Frames.get('number')           
l_mapFrameInfo[itr] = pcopy.deepcopy(l_frameInfo)    
itr+=1
```

---

name and number are read from an xml file which keeps on changing based on the values coming from XML file.

after operation:
all dictionaries name and number inside mydict gets the value of the last dict copied

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you post an example with input & output ?

Comment: If you don't want the values to be overwritten, why are you doing the copy?

Comment: Can you show us how your nesting looks, exactly? As I understood it, you want to copy something like `{'a': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]}`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If your copying doesn't do what you want, you use comprehensions to go deep enough to do the relevant operations by hand. In case of a dictionary that contains lists that contains dictionaries, this should do:

```
my_dict = {'a': [{'c': 1, 'd': 2}], 'b': [{'e': 3}]}
my_dict_copy = {key: [dict(entry) for entry in val] for key, val in my_dict.items()}
```

Which can be tested with:

```
my_dict['a'][0]['c'] = -1
print(my_dict['a'][0]['c'])
>> -1
print(my_dict_copy['a'][0]['c'])
>> 1
```

The copy was left untouched by the change in the original.